# Filter products in a category in Magento

Tags: category, filter

I have a category named "dog" and a sub-category named "leash". I sell adult leashes and puppy leashes and I don't want another subcategory. Is there a way my customer can filter on just puppy leashes without another sub-category?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an attribute called "type" and use it to filter inside the category without the need to create another subcategory.

Full guide [here](http://www.human-element.com/Blog/ArticleDetailsPage/tabid/91/ArticleID/68/Magento-Attributes-Using-Different-Filterable-Attributes-Per-Category.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

There's number of way to filter products:

1. By Category
2. By DROPDOWN type attribute
3. By Price

Create a new attribute of dropdown type, add it to attribute set of your dog leash products (or to default set if you don't use sets) and make category an anchor category. Voila, a filter.

Note! There's a handful of predefined attributes that while being technically a dropdown attributes can't be used that way, such as Country of Manufacture.